# How to get child job logs in parent job on child job failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to get child job logs in parent job irrespective of if child job passes or fails. Following code returns child jobs logs in parent job only when child job passes -

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('Hello') {

        steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
            echo 'In parent job'
            script {
                def result = build job: 'ChildJob', parameters: []
                 println result.getRawBuild().getLog()
            }
        }     
      }
    }  
}
```

Is there any way where on failure I can get child job logs in parent job?

Answer (score 1):

from https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

propagate (optional)
If set, then if the downstream build is anything but successful (blue ball), this step fails. If disabled, then this step succeeds even if the downstream build is unstable, failed, etc.; use the result property of the return value as needed.

This should exactly answer your question

Comment: Thanks @Holleoman for pointing that! But when I set `propagate: true`, on failure of downstream job, logs are not added to upstream job and when I set `propagate: false`, downstream job logs are added to upstream job but on failure of downstream job, upstream job is not marked as failed, it still marked as success.

Comment: Well, thats how Jenkins work. Either you fail and everything stops, or you ignore the failure and carry on. Maybe you have an option the check you log an set your job to unstable in the post phase?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game but I managed this with `propagate: false` like this:

```
script {
  def run = build(
    job: "job name here",
    propagate: false
  )
                
  println(run.rawBuild.getLog())

  currentBuild.result = run.getResult()
}
```